# How to group similar strings by the longest ending substring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a strange problem. I am trying to write code that groups strings that end with the longest same substring.

For example, I have a collection of strings:

```
["samsung.phone.com", "lg.phone.com", "phone.com", "camera.dsrl.nikon.com", "amd.gpu.com", "intel.cpu.com" ]
```

I want to create a dictionary where they will be grouped by the longest-ending string (excluding the last part - .com).

The dictionary should look like this:

```
{
"phone.com" : ["lg.phone.com", "samsung.phone.com"],
"camera.dsrl.nikon.com" : [], 
"amd.gpu.com": [], 
"intel.cpu.com": []
}
```

And if I add `"cpu.com"` to the collection, the new dictionary should look like this:

```
{
"phone.com" : ["lg.phone.com", "samsung.phone.com"],
"camera.dsrl.nikon.com" : [], 
"amd.gpu.com" : [], 
"cpu.com": ["intel.cpu.com"]
}
```

And if I add `"hello.samsung.phone.com"` to the collection, the new dictionary should look like this:

```
{
"phone.com": ["lg.phone.com"],
"samsung.phone.com": ["hello.samsung.phone.com"]
"camera.dsrl.nikon.com": [], 
"amd.gpu.com": [], 
"cpu.com": ["intel.cpu.com"]
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, the idea is to separate the domains. For example: cpu.com; from the subdomains, for example: inte.cpu.com

Comment: What if there is also the string `hello.samsung.phone.com`? Please show what the dictionary should look like. It isn't clear whether this should be grouped seperately from the other `phone.com` strings, and should instead be placed in a group with `samsung.phone.com`

Comment: I am so sorry; I miss this case. The changes are updated.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like what you really want is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but backwards.

Comment: Because there is no added string `"gpu.com"` in the collection

Comment: [Update] So I made a mistake: after adding `"hello.samsung.phone.com,"`, it should not appear in `"phone.com."`. Changes are updated!

Comment: What is this going to be used for? This will be very hard to search and update compared to a Trie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest code but it works (I think). The comments explain everything:

```js
/**
 * Filter a list by subdomain
 * @param {[string]} domList List of strings which represent domains and subdomains
 * @returns {} A dictionary having keys as subdomains and values as list of corresponding domains
 */
function filterBySubdomain(domList) {
  const dict = {}; // key: subdomain, value: list of domains

  // Assume that all elements of x are subdomains
  // Let each element of x be a key in dict
  domList.forEach((el) => (dict[el] = []));

  // For each subdomain, find all domains
  for (let i = 0; i < domList.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < domList.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j) {
        const subdomain = domList[j].substring(domList[j].indexOf(".") + 1);
        if (subdomain === domList[i]) {
          // x[i] is the subdomain of x[j]
          dict[domList[i]].push(domList[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // create a list of all domains found
  let mergedDomainList = [];
  for (const [subdomain, domainList] of Object.entries(dict)) {
    mergedDomainList = [...mergedDomainList, ...domainList];
  }

  // delete all keys which are domains but not subdomains.
  mergedDomainList.forEach((x) => {
    if (dict[x].length == 0) delete dict[x];
  });

  // Remove a domain from a list if it is a subdomain. 
  const toRemove = Object.keys(dict); // list of subdomains
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
    dict[key] = value.filter(function (el) {
      return !toRemove.includes(el);
    });
  }
  return dict;
}
```

It's best to step through the above algorithm with breakpoints and console logs to understand what's happening.

## Usage

```js
const x1 = [
  "samsung.phone.com",
  "lg.phone.com",
  "phone.com",
  "camera.dsrl.nikon.com",
  "amd.gpu.com",
  "intel.cpu.com",
];
const x2 = [
  "samsung.phone.com",
  "lg.phone.com",
  "phone.com",
  "camera.dsrl.nikon.com",
  "amd.gpu.com",
  "intel.cpu.com",
  "cpu.com",
];
const x3 = [
  "samsung.phone.com",
  "lg.phone.com",
  "phone.com",
  "camera.dsrl.nikon.com",
  "amd.gpu.com",
  "intel.cpu.com",
  "cpu.com",
  "hello.samsung.phone.com",
];
const result1 = filterBySubdomain(x1);
const result2 = filterBySubdomain(x2);
const result3 = filterBySubdomain(x3);

console.log(result1, "\n", result2, "\n", result3);
```

### Output

```
{
  'phone.com': [ 'samsung.phone.com', 'lg.phone.com' ],
  'camera.dsrl.nikon.com': [],
  'amd.gpu.com': [],
  'intel.cpu.com': []
} 
 {
  'phone.com': [ 'samsung.phone.com', 'lg.phone.com' ],
  'camera.dsrl.nikon.com': [],
  'amd.gpu.com': [],
  'cpu.com': [ 'intel.cpu.com' ]
} 
 {
  'samsung.phone.com': [ 'hello.samsung.phone.com' ],
  'phone.com': [ 'lg.phone.com' ],
  'camera.dsrl.nikon.com': [],
  'amd.gpu.com': [],
  'cpu.com': [ 'intel.cpu.com' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using a [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/eXvutE/1) like the one below

```
(?<!\.)([^\.]+)(?=\.)\.(.*)
```

What it does is simply splitting the given domain into a subdomain and main domain.

The code would look like this:

```js
const regex = /(?<!\.)([^\.]+)(?=\.)\.(.*)/

const list = ["samsung.phone.com", "lg.phone.com", "phone.com", "camera.dsrl.nikon.com", "amd.gpu.com", "intel.cpu.com"];

const result = {};

list.forEach(d => {
  const matches = d.match(regex);

  // matches[1] is the subdomain and 
  // matches[2] is the main domain
  // if an entry with the given main domain exists, 
  // just push the new one to it, 
  // else create a new entry
  result[matches[2]] ? result[matches[2]].push(d) : result[matches[2]] = [d]
})

console.log(result);
```

The output would be like this:

```
{
    phone.com:["samsung.phone.com", "lg.phone.com"]
    com:["phone.com"]
    ...
}
```